# Модельки и формы в django

Tags: python, django, form

Учу джанго и вопрос у меня в принципе простой, но нагуглить ответ у меня не получилось. В чем дело:
У меня есть model класса календарь:

```
class Calendar(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=63, name="name", help_text="Название")
    description = models.TextField(max_length=255, name="description", help_text="Описание")
    creator = models.CharField(max_length=63, name='author', help_text='Автор')
    path = models.CharField(max_length=63, name='path', help_text='Путь по которому получают этот календарь',
                            unique=True)
```

Мне нужно создавать объекты этого класса и записывать в бд. Все поля кроме пути получать из формы а path генерировать случайно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не согласен с другими ответами )))

Юзайте `save` или `pre_save`.

```
# model.save()
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.path:
        self.path = generate_path
    return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

```
# receiver
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Calendar, dispatch_uid='calendar.pre_save_gen_path')
def pre_save_gen_path(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if not instance.path:
        instance.path = instance.generate_path()
```

Если поле можно будет менять, то в форме в методе `get_object` если новый объект - вызывайте сигнал.

В общем, сигнал - более гибкое решение и эта логика будет располагаться рядом с моделью.

Вариант с `save` менее гибкий, вам придется убирать поле из формы, если поле обязательное.

Answer (score 1):

Очевидное решение с наследованием и перегрузкой `__init__` является неверным!!!

```
class Calendar(models.Model):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Calendar, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.path = self.generate_path()

    def generate_path(self) -> str:
        return str(randint(10 ** 6, 9 * 10 ** 6))

    name = models.CharField(max_length=63, name="name", help_text="Название")
    description = models.TextField(max_length=255, name="description", help_text="Описание")
    creator = models.CharField(max_length=63, name='author', help_text='Автор')
    path = models.CharField(max_length=63, name='path', help_text='Путь по которому получают этот календарь',
                            unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name} {self.description[:25]}"
```

Так как каждый раз при выгрузке из бд в память будет создаваться instance этого класса и path будет меняться. (наглядно видно при обновление страницы в админке, каждый раз новый path)

Решение вот такое (файл views.py)

```
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = NewCalendarForm(request.POST)
        form.instance.path = Calendar.generate_path() // Тут генерируем путь
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
```

__ models.py __

```
class Calendar(models.Model):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Calendar, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    @staticmethod
    def generate_path() -> str:
        return str(randint(10 ** 6, 9 * 10 ** 6))
```

Comment: С чего вы взяли что вариант с переопределением `__init__` неверный? Посмотрите мой ответ

Comment: этот вариант плох, ты оставляешь бизнес логику внутри view. Я бы вынес создание случайного пути, либо в метод save модели/формы, либо в метод clean формы

Comment: еще в сигнал можно вынести в pre_save -  проверять что пути нет и тогда создавать

Comment: Вариант с `__init__` будет работать если добавить проверку на то, что `path` не заполнен

Answer (score 1):

Не согласен с ответом @BlueScreen. Используйте вариант с переопределением `__init__` метода:

```
class Calendar(models.Model):
    # ... Ваши поля
    def __init__(self, name, description, creator, path=None):
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
        self.creator = creator
        
        if path:
            self.path = path
        else:
            self.path = generate_random_path()
```

`generate_random_path` - ваша функция, которая будет генерировать рандомный `path`. При загрузке из базы в `self.path` будет попадать значение из базы, иначе генерироваться случайное. Для надёжности можете добавить `NOT NULL` правило в БД для поля

Comment: лучше переопределять в методе save. В методе init Вам будет сложно определить уникальность поля. Так как между созданием экземпляра модели и ее сохранением может пройти много времени. В итоге уникальность на момент создания может быть потеряна в момент сохранения